# Shiny server output if-statement error

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I'm getting a `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` in the following code and I am at a loss to why.

`output$Strength<-renderText(
    if(input$Motiv>=((input$Tempt-input$Rew)/(input$Tempt-input$Pun))){
      "Strong!"
    }else{
      "Weak!"
    }
  )`

The rest of the Shiny App runs just fine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see the actual content of `input` before the if? Could you include in the question the result of `print(input)` executed just before the if?

Comment: When I take out this statement, the app runs fine.

This is the associated UI code:

`textOutput("Strength")`

Comment: Yes, but that error is probably due to the fact that `input` does not contain one (or more) of the columns you are trying to access with `$`. Could you include the result of calling `print(input)` inside the `renderText` function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "Could you include the result of calling print(input) inside the renderText function?"

Comment: Substitute the code you posted by this one `output$Strength<-renderText(print(input))`. This will print the content of the variable `input` in the console. The idea is to check its content. Your code is trying to access 3 columns inside that variable: `Tempt`, `Rew` and `Pun`. Maybe one of them is void, hence your error.

Comment: Okay, I did that and now it says, 

`Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`

`Tempt`, `Rew`, and `Pun` are all `numericInput` functions with `value=50` at the outset.

Comment: Ok, it's a list, not a data.frame. Try with `print(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, input)))` instead of `print(input)`

Comment: `environments cannot be coerced to other types`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's happening then. Maybe another user will be able to answer the question. If you're using RStudio, I would try to analyse the content of your variable with the debugger to check if it contains what it's supposed to have. I would also include more information in the question. For instance, how you create the variable `input` in the first place.

Comment: Or, just post a minimal reproducible example, along with your error message. It's almost impossible to figure out what your bug is without this information...

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
output$Strength<-renderText(
    if(input$Motiv[1] >= ((input$Tempt[1]-input$Rew[1])/(input$Tempt[1]-input$Pun[1]))){
      "Strong!"
    }else{
      "Weak!"
    }
)
```